# ListFeed.aspx not returning all items

Tags: 2010, rss

So I have a site, which I want to get an RSS Feed with specific Items returned.

I created a view called Display Only, and I did this:

https://website.com/_layouts/listfeed.aspx?List=cba9a43f-7542-436a-23f6-7bc6137f8b06&View=aeccf235-e988-4ea7-bf5c-a6f7403894c1

So I pass in the list id and the view id, but I do not get all the fields.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you not get back, the fields or the items? I first though you meant items (question title), which is probably because of paging in the view, although your question body states something else

Comment: Hi, I figured it out a few minutes after posting this. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

So I figured this out.

When I was using the url I though in order to get the items back I needed to pass the list ID and the view ID. But it seems that that is not how it works.

First I must go to Site Settings and under Site Administration click on RSS and enable it if it is not enabled.

[image]
[image]

Once i have done that I need to go back to the list and click on List Settings. Under Communications there is RSS Settings,

[image]

and here is where you chose what items you want to display and in what order, when you click the RSS button for your list.

[image]

So now you can just click the RSS feed button and the list items you selected  to display should now show up.

[image]